# Adding conditions in rails include

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

going directly to my problem.

```
render :json => projects.to_json(:only => ['name', 'id'],:include => {:client => {:only => ['name']}, :deliverables => {:only => ['name', 'id'], :include => {:tasks => {:only => ['name','id']} } } })
```

This is how my controller responds for json request. Now my problem is that it lists all the deliverables & tasks that are in given project but here I want to respond with tasks & deliverables that meets certain condition like all that are created in specific month.

Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I did, in project model

> has_many :uncompleted_deliverables,
>                     :class_name => 'Deliverable',
>                     :conditions => 'completed = false'

The same applies to deliverable model

```
has_many :uncompleted_tsks, :class_name => 'Task', :conditions => 'completed = false'
```

And then responded json in following way,

```
 format.json { render :json => projects.to_json(:only => ['name', 'id'],
                                                 :include => {:client => {:only => ['name']}, :uncompleted_deliverables => {:only => ['name', 'id'], :include => {:uncompleted_tsks => {:only => ['name','id']} } } }) }
```

Anyway thanks guys for your response..

Answer (score 0):

Could you just include a proc? (see end of documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html))

I guess the code could look something like that:

in you Project model:

```
def to_json(options={})
  tasks_json = Proc.new { |options|
    options[:builder].tasks do
      selected_tasks = tasks.select {|t| t.created_at > 30.days.ago } # or whatever your condition is
      selected_tasks.each do |t|
        options[:builder].task do
          options[:builder].tag!('id', t.id)
          options[:builder].tag!('name', t.name)
        end
      end
    end }

  options.merge!(:procs => [tasks_json])
end
```

Would that work for you?